# Eliminar datos de la base de datos tras un tiempo de espera

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo que hacer que se elimine un dato de MySQL en un determinado tiempo que yo le indique. Por ejemplo, ponerle como límite 10 segundos y que el contador añ llegar a 10 elimine un dato de la base de datos. Y la verdad no sé cómo hacerlo.

La página se trata de que se guarden y muestren las IP conectadas a la web. Pero necesito eliminar la IP de la BD del usuario que ya no está en la página. La página está en PHP.

Este es el código que tengo. Hasta el momento guarda la IP y la fecha de los usuarios conectados a la página web, y recorre la base de datos para listar y mostrar las IP de los usuarios que han ingresado:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("servidor", "usuario", "contraseña", "bd");
if (!$conn) {
    die("Conexion Fallida: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$fecha=date("Y-m-d");
$consulta = "INSERT INTO usuario(ip, fecha) VALUES('$ip','$fecha')";
$respuesta = "SELECT * FROM usuario";
$Re = mysqli_query($conn,$respuesta);
while ($pid = mysqli_fetch_array($Re)) {
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    echo "<strong>su ip es ".$pid['ip']."</strong><br>"; 
}

    $dato = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE ip='$dato'");
    if ($result && (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)) {


    }else{
        $resu = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta);

    }
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Necesitamos que muestres lo que has intentado y  a partir de ahí podremos ayudarte. El primer paso debes darlo tú, ensayando un código, aunque se trate de empezar desde cero. Saludos.

Comment: Te recomiendo empezar por leer un poco de variables de sesión eso te puede dar una idea de por donde iniciar.

Comment: Este tipo de tareas se ejecutan x medio de un programador o scheduler de tu SO. Si estás en Linux con un cron que ejecute el comando de borrar cada 10s será suficiente. Te animo a que busques CRON por internet y mires como hacer el que te interese

Comment: Como dice @Jakala, lo más simple sería programar todo el código en un archivo PHP y mandar a ejecutar ese archivo cada 10 segundos desde un cron (programador de tareas) de tu sistema operativo. Dado que esto debe ejecutarse con mucha frecuencia, posiblemente conviene manejar una **conexión persistente** en este caso, para evitar intentos de conexión a la base de datos cada 10 segundos.

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 1):

Ya que trabajas con MySQL, te propongo resolverlo mediante eventos.

En primer lugar, añade un campo instante que almacene la hora con segundos, además de la fecha:

```
ALTER TABLE usuario ADD instante datetime;
```

Después crea este evento:

```
CREATE EVENT borrador
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 SECOND
  DO
    DELETE FROM usuario
      WHERE instante < NOW() - INTERVAL 10 SECOND;
```

No olvides activar los eventos en tu servidor:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Y recuerda incluir en tu `INSERT` el campo `instante`:

```
INSERT INTO usuario (ip, fecha, instante)
  VALUES ('192.168.0.1',NOW(),NOW());
```

Una vez en marcha, ningún registro permanecerá en esa tabla más de 10 segundos.